# Java Class/es - Almacenamiento

Tags: java

Tengo una pregunta sobre el almacenamiento de la classes, yo había creado una pregunta hablando del almacenamiento, me habían respondido que **TODAS** las clases se almacenan (`ClaseC a = new ClaseC()`).

---

Entonces, cada vez que usaría `new Random()` estaría almacenando otra clase mas?, como podria crear una clase como "`Random()`"?

Comment: ¿A que te referís con "todas las clases se almacenan"? ¿Hablas de las instancias?

Comment: @MatiEzelQ Exacto, me dijeron que se instanciabas muchas clases esto podría causar retrasos.

Comment: Lo que llamas "clases" son en realidad "objetos" (instancias de una clase) . Si haces `Random r1 = new Random(); Random r2 = new Random();` creas dos objetos (la clase es una sola)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de lo que te dice el compañero @MatiEzelQ, las instancias tienen un ciclo de vida y este tiene que ver con la [recolección de basura](http://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-garbage-collector/).

Actualmente hay dos "tipos" de espacios para instancias:

- Young generation
- Old generation

Para cada tipo de espacios existen diversos contenedores.

#### Young generation/Nueva generación

Este espacio contiene 3 contenedores:

- Eden: aquí se almacenan los objetos que acabamos de instanciar.
- Survivor 0: Aquí se almacenan los objetos que no tienen referencia en el momento de pasar el recolector de basura.
- Survivor 1: Si al volver a pasar el recolector de basura encuentra aún objetos sin referencia en el Survivor 0, se pasan al Survivor 1.

#### Old generation/Vieja generación

Si cuando el recolector pasa por el Survivor 1 encuentra aún que los objetos allí siguen sin tener referencia, éstos pasan a ser parte de la vieja generación.

Esta generación contiene 2 contenedores:

- Ternured: aquí llegan los objetos que no siguen sin tener referencia cuando el recolector pasó por el Survivor 1. El recolector pasará por aquí generalmente **cuando el espacio se encuentre lleno**, liberando los objetos de forma definitiva.
- Permanent: aquí la JVM carga las clases que necesita para su funcionamiento. El recolector no pasará por aquí porque estas instancias son permanentes.

Comment: _Gracias por responder, Lo que estoy haciendo es que por cada jugador que entre se cree un nuevo objecto(ClassE a = new ClassE(jugador)), y este Objecto lo almaceno dentro de un Set<ClassE> entonces, por mas que almacene mas de 100 jugador no causara retrasos?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que ya hay mucho más de 100 objetos cargados en la JVM. Es una cantidad muy pequeña, para que haya un overflow la cantidad debe ser muy grande.

Comment: Muchas gracias la verdad!, muy informativa tu respuesta!

Answer (score 3):

Si bien entiendo, el problema que decís es que mientras instancies mas clases, vas a estar ocupando mas memoria RAM con tu programa. Si te interesa una instancia dispone de dos lugares de almacenamiento(los dos en la ram):

En el heap se almacenan las instancias de tus clases en sí. Es decir, al hacer un `new ClaseA`, lo único que estás haciendo es crear la instancia en el heap. Ahora si hacés `ClaseA a = new ClaseA();` estás creando una variable en el STACK(llamada: a) que tiene una referencia hacia la instancia, la cúal se almaceno en el HEAP.

Te dejo una imagen donde podés ver, talvez, mas claramente lo que trate de explicarte: 
[image: Imagen]

Espero haber entendido bien tu duda.

Comment: $Gracias por responder, Lo que yo estoy haciendo es que por cada jugador que entre se cree un nuevo objecto(`ClassE a = new ClassE(jugador)`), y este Objecto lo almaceno dentro de un `Set<ClassE>` entonces, por mas que almacene mas de 100 jugador no causara retrasos?

Comment: @Javadoub no entiendo bien tu nueva duda. Si bien hay una relación entre memoria y rendimiento de una aplicación, no encuentro una relación entre crear un objeto y almacenarlo en un `Set`. ¿Qué es lo que te preocupa de eso?

Comment: (`setName.add(this)` <- en el contructor) Lo agrego a un Set<> para después remover el "objecto" creado (`remove(this)`)

Comment: @Javadoub no tiene mucho sentido lo que explicas. Creo que será mejor si colocas el código relevante y explicas cuál es el problema que tienes. Te recomiendo que hagas esto en una nueva pregunta.